Handling CORS Preflight Requests in Flutter Web Integration Tests
I'm facing issues with CORS preflight requests in my Flutter web integration tests. Here's a summary of my setup and the problem:
Setup:

Flutter Web Integration Tests: Using flutter drive.
Backend APIs: External APIs used for testing.
Local Proxy Server: Using Express.js to handle CORS and proxy requests.

Problem:
When running tests on Flutter web, CORS preflight requests (OPTIONS) are triggered for my API calls, causing issues. These preflight requests don't occur on Android and iOS.
What I Have Tried:

Proxy Server: Configured to handle CORS and forward requests to the actual APIs.
Chrome Configuration: Ran Chrome with web security disabled for testing.

Question:
Is there a better way to handle or avoid CORS preflight requests in this setup? Any tips on configuring the proxy or Flutter tests to bypass these preflight requests?
Thanks in advance!

The main thing in CORS related issue is that all the configuration needed is about backend, not anywhere else.

If you can somehow make your request simple ie not triggering a preflight, so much the better.
